# ¿Cómo lograr borrar ciertos archivos de varios folders en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

como puedo lograr borrar varios archivos *.txt* que tengo en distintas sub-carpetas. Por ejemplo en la carpeta `C:\\TEST\\` tengo `C:\\TEST\\Test1` `C:\\TEST\\Test2` y dentro esas sub-carpetas ***Test1 y Test2*** tengo muchos archivos *.txt* que deseo eliminar.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import glob, os

directory = 'C:\\TEST\\'
os.chdir(directory)
files=glob.glob('*.txt')
for filename in files:
    os.unlink(filename)
    print("Borrando archivo: ", filename)
```

Pero no me borra los *.txt* que tengo dentro de las sub-carpetas solo de la carpeta principal.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desafortunadamente tendrías que hacer algunos cambios ya que, a menos que trabajes con Python 3.5+, el módulo `glob` no cuenta con recursión.

En Python 3.5+ es posible hacer algo como esto:

```
for archivo in glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True):
    # ...
```

En Python 2, lo que puedes intentar es una mezcla de [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) con [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html):

```
import os
import fnmatch


ruta = 'C:\\TEST\\'
for raiz, directorios, archivos in os.walk(ruta):
    for archivo in fnmatch.filter(archivos, '*.txt'):
        # Es necesario hacer un join con la raiz
        os.unlink(os.path.join(raiz, archivo))
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que usar `os.walk` o algunas de sus funciones hermanas para recorrer recursivamente un directorio e ir borrando los archivos que quieras.

Mira [este enlace](http://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com.es/2015/09/explorando-directorios-con-listdir-walk.html) donde se explica relativamente bien en castellano.