# Borrar varios folders en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Me podrían asesorar, tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo miles de carpetas que a su vez esta tiene varias sub-carpetas, hay específicamente una sub-carpeta que esta lleva por nombre "0".

*Ejemplo:*

```
├ DISCO_1 (CARPETA_Principal)
|  ├─ 2014353(SUB-CARPETA)
      -(SUB-Carpeta"0") #[Carpeta que se desea borrar]

|  ├─ 2014354 (SUB-CARPETA)
      -(SUB-Carpeta"0") #[Carpeta que se desea borrar]

|  └─ 2014355 (SUB-CARPETA)
      -(SUB-Carpeta"0") #[Carpeta que se desea borrar]
```

Esta es una carpeta que no me interesa y lo que quiero es borrar todas estas sub-carpetas "0"

Se que es con:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('C:\\Test\\')
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que estás usando Python 2, puedes hacer algo muy parecido a la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2060/100) que di a la pregunta [¿Cómo lograr borrar ciertos archivos de varios folders en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2056/100) haciendo uso de `os.walk` y `fnmatch`.

Teniendo como estructura de ejemplo:

```
carpeta
│── subcarpeta1
│   │── 0
│   │   │── 0.txt
│   │── 1
│   │── 2
│── subcarpeta2
│   │── 0
│   │   │── 0.txt
│   │── 1
│   │── 2
│── 0
│   │── 0.txt
```

Puedes usar algo como esto:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil

ruta = 'C:\\Test\\'
for raiz, directorios, archivos in os.walk(ruta):
    for directorio in fnmatch.filter(directorios, '0'):
        # Es necesario hacer un join con la raiz
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(raiz, directorio))
```

Resultado:

```
carpeta
│── subcarpeta1
│   │── 1
│   │── 2
│── subcarpeta2
│   │── 1
│   │── 2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho tu ayuda.

Tengo una pregunta, ¿es posible que los archivos que tengo en una sub-carpeta osea en vez de la carpeta "0" que tengo, sea la carpeta "1" pueda moverlos a la carpeta raiz?

No se si me este explicando bien

Comment: @Armando quizas sea mejor que formules otra pregunta, porque quizas sea mejor para encontrala en un futuro para otros usuarios, que busquen como mover ficheros o algo asi. Saludos